# E-mail notification if new WordPress user account is pending

Tags: wordpress

I wan't to have a e-mail notification if a new WordPress (Buddypress) user account is pending. I want to activate the accounts manually so a notification would be nice. Any ideas?

Comment: `bp_core_signup_user` is the hook you should use for this.

Comment: Any idea on how the code should look like? I'm not a pro coder :-)

Comment: Please see my answer below for an example of how to use the hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function my_function( $user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta ) {
    // Send the email notification.
    wp_mail( 'me@example.com', $user_login . ' has just registered', 'Feel free to log in and activate this new member.' );
}
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'my_function', 10, 5 );
```

In this example, if a user registers with a username of `joe`, then the email notification you will get will look like this:

Email subject line: *joe has just registered*

Email body: *Feel free to log in and activate this new member.*

Comment: Thank you very much! Works!

Comment: Do you know if there is a hook for when the admin approves the user? It would be nice if the user gets a automatic e-mail that his user account is approved by the admin. I know I'm stretching my luck :-)

Comment: There sure is. See: `bp_core_activated_user`

Comment: I'm trying to add the function (bp_core_activated_user) but I'm getting errors. I based it upon your function (bp_core_signup_user). Could you point me in the right direction Henri?

Comment: Hi @Gerard - what errors are you getting? Do you want to open a new question (tag it with 'BuddyPress') and I'll take a look to see where you're going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [New User Approve](https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/), will achieve this. Install it and activate it, then tick the option in the General tab of Settings to "Anyone can register". And when a user tries to register you will get an email asking to confirm the new used.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried that and the plugin does not send an e-mail. I'm not the only one for whom this plugin does not work.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other user app plugins? like http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to send the notification to multiple admins|moderators you can use the code below.

```
/**
 * E-mail notification if new WordPress user account is pending
*/
function my_function( $user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta ){

$to = 'mail1@example.com';

$body = 'New user on pending signups list';

$headers = array(
     'Content-type: text/html',
     'Cc: Email 2 <mail2@example.com>',
     'Cc: Email 3 <mail3@example.com>',
);

wp_mail( $to, $user_login . ' has just registered', $body, $headers ); 

}
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'my_function', 10, 5 );
```